# codeigniter database caching 'TRUE' stop webpage

Tags: database, codeigniter, caching

I want to turn on database caching into my CodeIgniter website for this I have used following code in database.php file.

```
    $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;  
    $db['default']['cachedir'] = 'application.cache';
```

And I have already created a folder, name cache inside application directory and give permission 0777.

when I run my website, it shows error - **this web page isn't working.**
the same code is perfect works on my localhost (xampp server).

Did I forget to include anything?   Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a relative path instead of '.'[dot].

But if you want to enabled database query caching then make your 'cache_on' to TRUE

```
$db['default']['cache_on'] = TRUE;  
$db['default']['cachedir'] = 'application/cache';
```

if above line not works try this:

```
$db['default']['cachedir'] = APPPATH . 'cache';
```

After that whichever query you want to store in cache use this feature

```
 // Turn caching on
 $this->db->cache_on();

 // Turn caching off for this one query
 $this->db->cache_off();
```

**Notes:**

- CodeIgniter’s query caching system happens dynamically when your
  pages are viewed. When caching is enabled, the first time a web page is loaded, the query result object will be serialized and stored in a
  text file on your server. The next time the page is loaded the cache file will be used instead of accessing your database.
- Only read-type (SELECT) queries can be cached not Write-type (INSERT, UPDATE, etc.) queries

The caching system permits you clear caches So whenever DB updated clear related catching also.When the page loaded it again caching updated queries.

[Read this for deleting caching](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/caching.html)

Comment: Thanks, how can we use this if we want to display updated data also?   Whenever I want to see updated data I have to delete the cache files inside cache folder.